# Execute one gradle task

Tags: gradle

I've this two tasks:

```
war {
    webInf { from 'src/main/resources/WEB-INF' }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': versioning.info.display
    }
}

task createDemoWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-demo-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    copy {
        from 'scopes'
        include 'configuration.demo.properties'
        into 'src/main/resources/'
    }
}

task createDevelopmentWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-dev-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    copy {
        from 'scopes/'
        include 'configuration.development.properties'
        into 'src/main/resources/'
    }
}
```

Both tasks are trying to copy a property file from`scopes` folder to `src/main/resources/` folder.

I only run one task, however two files are copied in `src/main/resources/` (`configuration.demo.properties` and `configuration.development,properties`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use two copy specifications at the configuration phase (note, copy specification in that case doesn't configure your task, but add some extra action to it's configuration). That means, your files are getting copied during configuration. That's all because of this:

```
copy {
    ...
}
```

You have to run it during execution, to do that, try to move it into the `doLast` or `doFirst` closure, like so (for both tasks):

```
task createDemoWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-demo-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from 'scopes'
            include 'configuration.demo.properties'
            into 'src/main/resources/'
        }
    }
}
```

In that case, files will be copied only if task will be executed, right before the execution.

Comment: It's really strange this behaviour, isn't it? I had no idea about configuration execution... phases. Could you get me some link in order to figure out a bit about it?

Comment: That could seems to be a little bit odd at first, but then you realize it, it becomes very clear. You can read about build lifecycle int the official user guide https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, I've a task like: `task createDists(dependsOn: [createDemoWar, createDevelopmentWar])`. When I run this `createDists` task, two wars are generated, however any file is in `src/main/resources`